# SQL - How to Categorize a Case Statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

In this sample dataset, I have some **Colors** : "Red" and "Blue"
and some **Fruit**: "Apple" and "Grapes" associated with a person/name.

[image]

My goal is to add a column for each of these groupings, called **"Colors"** and **Fruit**. These newly added columns would count +1 whenever the value is > 0 for each of their respective grouping.

For example if either "Red" or "Blue" contain a value > 0, we will add +1 to **Colors**. For John Smith, since both the Red and Blue columns contain a value > 0, the **Colors** column will be 2. Here is the expected output:

[image]

I know case statements can add 1 or 0, but how do we do this when we have 2 columns per grouping?

Comment: please (please!) don't use images of data, just copy paste that data as text instead. Right now I cannot see either of your images as the domain is blocked to me - but I can read your text. There are many other benefits to using text instead of images https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Do you need: #1. Calculate shown columns in a query; #2. Add the columns into the table structure.

Comment: btw: CASE is an **expression** not a statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  *,
  ((CASE WHEN apple > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + (CASE WHEN WHEN grapes > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) as fruit,
  ((CASE WHEN red > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + (CASE WHEN blue > 0 THEN 1ELSE 0 END)) as colors
from table
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not need in CASE.

```sql
SELECT blue, red, (blue > 0) + (red > 0) colors,
       apple, grapes, (apple > 0) + (grapes > 0) fruit
FROM source_table
```

The values in source table shouldn't be NULL.

Comment: I like this answer better than using a case statement. Depending on the version of sql, you might have to put explicit data types at the end so it returns a number instead of a bool

Comment: @Jacky The question tagged as MySQL-relative, so explicit convertion not needed.

Answer (score 1):

assuming the source data is in a pivoted state

```
with cte as (
select 'john' as name, 2 as blue, 3 as red, 2 as apple, 4 as grape union all
select 'tom', 0 , 8, 0, 0
)
select
      name
    , blue
    , red
    , coalesce((blue > 0),0) 
      + coalesce((red > 0),0)
      as colours
    , apple
    , grape
    , coalesce((apple > 0),0) 
      + coalesce((grape > 0),0)
      as fruits
from cte
```

> ```
> name | blue | red | colours | apple | grape | fruits
> :--- | ---: | --: | ------: | ----: | ----: | -----:
> john |    2 |   3 |       2 |     2 |     4 |      2
> tom  |    0 |   8 |       1 |     0 |     0 |      0
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8c23808aaae4b49cea582aea638adfb3)*